# JSON:API specification vs Serialize an object using NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

According to https://jsonapi.org/format/

*A JSON object MUST be at the root of every JSON:API request and response containing data. This object defines a document’s “top level”.
A document MUST contain at least one of the following top-level members:

**data**: the document’s “primary data”

**errors**: an array of error objects

**meta**: a meta object that contains non-standard meta-information.*

So a valid JSON document considering this meta, data and error elements should look like (just an example):

```
{
  "meta": {
    "uuid": "e77d8a4b-dc00-445c-8cf6-118704c5525b",
    "key": "key123",
    "api_version": "1.0"
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "agent",
    "attributes": {
      "uuid": "a4470f04-c6eb-45b2-9487-d1cecc869b5f",
      "name": "hostname",
      "operating_system": "Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0)",
    }
  }
}
```

Using C# and Newtonsoft.Json.SerializeObject to serialize this object:

```
public class Device : Meta
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string guid { get; set; }
    public string api_version { get; set; }
}
```

then:

```
var device = new Device { Name = Environment.MachineName, key = "key123", guid = "41afe993-2629-40a2-98bb-4cbd4e5c5bb0",api_version = "1.0"};
var deviceJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(device, Formatting.Indented);
```

i get a json document:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "SOLMOB007",
  "Software": [],
  "key": "key123",
  "guid": "41afe993-2629-40a2-98bb-4cbd4e5c5bb0",
  "api_version": "1.0"
}
```

Can one explain me, if i have to implement (data, error, meta elements handling) in my model classes or can i instruct the serializer to add them when calling the serializeobject/the constructor?

thanks a lot!

Christian

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io?share=NHj65CY5Xesbjm9JLM9m

Comment: You're looking at the spec for `JSON:API`, not the spec for `JSON`. Json.NET doesn't know anything about `JSON:API`, so you will need to define those `meta`, `data`, `errors` objects yourself.

Comment: If you want to create a JSON document with `meta`, `data` and `errors` properties, you will need to define an object which has properties called `meta`, `data` and `errors`. `Device` should have a `meta` property, rather than inheriting from `Meta`.